# Find the number of a row that contains two specific values?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a table of information with multiple columns. The first column is "Date" (range A:A) and the second column is "Name" (range B:B). When I enter a date into cell Q1 and a name into cell R1, I need a formula that will find which row contains both of those values and output the row number.

I feel like I need to use the match function but can't quite figure it out. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `MATCH` in an "array formula" like this

`=MATCH(1,(A:A=Q1)*(B:B=R1),0)`

which needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....or add an `INDEX` function and the formula can be entered normally

`=MATCH(1,INDEX((A:A=Q1)*(B:B=R1),0),0)`

Comment: So many years later, you saved me!