# Excel: Seeing, if a person is already in the list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have a list of names and surnames and I want to have the possibility to test if a name/surname-combination is already in the list. I thought about using MATCH, but this can only do one value, I think.

Example:

```
  | A    | B       | C | D   | E    | F          |
1 | Name | Surname |   | Doe | John | is in list |
2 | Doe  | John    |   |     |      |            |
3 | Grey | Dorian  |   |     |      |            |
… | …    | …       |   |     |      |            |
```

Where `A2:B100` is the data, `D1:E1` is my input, and `F1` should contain some function that outputs 'is in list' if the name/surname combination in `D1:E1` is found somehwhere in my data `A2:B100` and otherwise 'is not in list'. Any ideas on how to do it?

EDIT: My question is slightly different to the possible duplicate, because I am not asking *where* the match is, I'm just asking *whether* there is a match.

Comment: Just do a google search for `match with 2 values`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the number of a row that contains two specific values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307976/find-the-number-of-a-row-that-contains-two-specific-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10, D1, $B$1:$B$10, E1)
```

[Returns a number greater than 0 for a match]

You'll probably have to use at least two of these, considering your surname and name can be interchanged (i.e. one where D is matched against Name, and E against surname like in the above, then a second one where D is matched against surname and E against name), and last wrap everything in an `IF` to get your displayed result.

Comment: You are using concatenation for the first solution, so there is the problem I mentioned with that in the other answers.

Comment: I just understood the `COUNTIFS` function. I think this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: @Wauzl You're right. Nice catch, I didn't think of the possibility of having something like "Mary/Annbaker" with "Maryann/Baker". I will remove the first part then.

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A100&B2:B100=D1&E1))
```

You could wrap it in an `IF` statement like this:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A100&B2:B100=D1&E1)),"is in list","not in list")
```

---

More rigorous version (as per your comments)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100=D1)*(B2:B100=E1))
```

Comment: This doesn't work in some cases: If you have "Mary/Annbaker" in the list, it will match against "Maryann/Baker".

Comment: @Wauzl -- Updated to be more rigorous. Note that `SUMPRODUCT` used this way is essentially just replicating a `COUNTIFS` formula.

Comment: So, `A2:A100=D1` and `B2:B100` both give a list of 0s and 1s that are multiplied via `*` element-wise. Then `SUMPRODUCT` gives me the sum of the result list?

Comment: Why, can't I just use SUM then?

Comment: @Wauzl Actually you can, but the SUM formula doesn't know to do the element-wise multiplication unless you explicitly tell it to by entering the formula with ctrl+shift+enter. SUMPRODUCT expects to iterate element-wise so it works without as normal

Comment: I just noticed: This solution matches empty cells with empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following

```
+---+--------+-----------+---------------+
|   |   A    |     B     |       C       |
+---+--------+-----------+---------------+
| 1 |  Name  |  Surname  | Concatenation |
| 2 |  Doe   |  John     | DoeJohn       |
| 3 |  Grey  |  Dorian   | GreyDorian    |
+---+--------+-----------+---------------+
```

where cell C2 is like `=TRIM(A2)&TRIM(B2)`

Now you just have to use the following formula to catch if the name/surname is in the list (for example you can write it into the F2 cell):

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(D2)&TRIM(E2),C:C,1,0)),"is NOT in the list","is in the list")
```

where in column D you have the name and in column E you have the surname of the person you are looking for.

Comment: Here is the same problem like with SUMPRODUCT: It will match "Mary/Annbaker" with "Maryann/Baker"

Comment: You can just change the concatenation rules. Instead of transform "Doe" and "John" in "DoeJohn" you can just transform them into "name:Doe|surname:John"